# Sorting bubbles in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to sort the bubbles in d3.js force layout so the bigger ones will be on top and smaller ones in the bottom?

[image: screen shot]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-plfvcj